# SQL: insert total count row after joining table

Tags: sql-server

The first step is to join `staff` and `customer` together. The second step is to count the distinct product_id. My target is to add the total(sum) field under the result table.
Thanks.

`staff`

```
staff_ID     Name     cust_id          
1            Tom       101   
1            Tom       101
1            Tom       105
2            Peter     102
2            Peter     104
3            Billy     103
```

`customer`

```
cust_id    product_id        
101             A1
102             A2
103             A3
104             A4
105             A5
```

My work:

```
SELECT a.staff_name,COUNT(DISTINCT a.product_id)
FROM (SELECT distinct a.staff_id, a.staff_name, a.cust_id
     FROM staff)a
LEFT JOIN customer b ON a.cust_id=b.cust_id
GROUPBY a.staff_name
```

What I want is to add the **total** column below the count.

```
Name     count         
Tom       2   
Peter     2
Billy     1
Total     5
```

Comment: It seems unfortunate that so far you've not felt any answers to your previous questions were worth accepting?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

Regarding the "Total", as @MatBailie correctly pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399012/sql-insert-total-count-row-after-joining-table/71399133?noredirect=1#comment126202013_71399133):

> The aggregate of multiple COUNT(DISTINCT) rows CAN NOT be guaranteed to be summable. If two staff members share the same product_id the summary value will be LESS THAN the sum of its members.

So for this sample data set:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ee6c6394e59a0b371c1d67d1a0cf2cb)*

| cust_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A1 |
| 102 | A2 |
| 103 | A3 |
| 104 | A4 <== Same product |
| 105 | A5 |
| 105 | A4 <== Same product |

Using [GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) yields a "Total" value of 5:

> ```
> SELECT  COALESCE(a.staff_name, 'Total') AS Staff_Name
>       , COUNT(DISTINCT b.product_id) AS [Count]
> FROM   staff a LEFT JOIN customer b ON a.cust_id=b.cust_id
> GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.staff_name);
> ```

**Results:**

| Staff_Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Billy | 1 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Tom | 3 |
| Total | 5 ** |

Whereas calculating a simple sum of the totals, yields a "Total" value of 6.  So just be aware of the difference.

| Staff_Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Billy | 1 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Tom | 3 |
| Total | 6 ** |

---

**Original (Wrong Answer):**

Can't remember where I saw this answer, but ... assuming `Staff_Name` is never null, you could use [GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to obtain the total. <s>That said calculating grand totals is usually more of a front-end job.</s>

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.staff_name, 'Total') AS Staff_Name
      , COUNT(DISTINCT b.product_id) AS [Count]
FROM   staff a LEFT JOIN customer b ON a.cust_id=b.cust_id
GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.staff_name);
```

Comment: Good luck calculating a summary line's `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the front end. (Depending on the Op's data, it may be summable, but in principle a COUNT(DISTINCT) should always be calculated in the database.)

Comment: No, I mean summing the results of the query. i.e. Most web apps and reporting tools can easily sum() the lines above.

Comment: The aggregate of multiple `COUNT(DISTINCT)` rows CAN NOT be guaranteed to be summable. If two staff members share the same product_id the summary value will be LESS THAN the sum of its members.

Comment: @MatBailie - Fair point. I took their requirement to mean a simple sum, but it's possible that's not the case.

Comment: If you thought that, then your answer is wrong (or internally contradictory). Your answer currently does it the way I described.

Comment: @MatBailie - Just tested it and you're right. It's been a while since I used ROLLUP. I should've re-reviewed the docs on that one. Let me fix the answer

Comment: @MatBailie - Thanks for setting me straight on that one. I hate giving out wrong information.

Comment: Great answer. If `staff_name` is nullable then for the first column you can use `CASE WHEN GROUPING(staff_name) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE staff_name END`. Also for more complex subtotal scenarios you can replace `ROLLUP` with `GROUPING SETS`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT s.staff_name, COUNT(DISTINCT b.product_id), SUM(count) Total
FROM staff s
INNER JOIN customer b ON b.cust_id = s.cust_id
GROUP BY s.staff_name
```

Comment: What about the total row?

Comment: @MatBailie Almost forgotten. Answer updated!

Comment: That adds a column, not a row.  It tries to sum a column called `count`, which doesn't exist.  Hint: Look at the other answer.